# facebook decoing my url?

Tags: facebook, url, decode

I have created an application for facebook's fan pages. Among other things I save the page's Id. Since the page's Id alone is of no intrest, I cross it against facebook's graph api. For most pages this works well, as I can get a clear response, but from some reason, for pages in hebrew I get the following response:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/\u0025D7\u002596\u0025D7\u002599\u0025D7\u002595\u0025D7\u002594-\u0025D7\u0025A7\u0025D7\u002595\u0025D7\u0025A8\u0025D7\u002599\u0025D7\u0025A5/189302531095358
```

what is this? Is this value encoded? How can I decode it?

Thank you